# How to change the background colour of selected node in TreeView when FullRowSelect is true in C#

Tags: c#, treeview

The title pretty much sums it up: I am looking for a way to change the colour of highlighted node when FullRowSelect property is on. I have tried the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class ExtendedTreeView : TreeView
{
public ExtendedTreeView()
{
    this.DrawMode = TreeViewDrawMode.OwnerDrawText;
}
protected override void OnDrawNode(DrawTreeNodeEventArgs e)
{
    TreeNodeStates state = e.State;
    Font font = e.Node.NodeFont ?? e.Node.TreeView.Font;
    Color fore = e.Node.ForeColor;
    if (fore == Color.Empty) fore = e.Node.TreeView.ForeColor;
    if (e.Node == e.Node.TreeView.SelectedNode)
    {
        fore = SystemColors.HighlightText;
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(254, 128, 62)), e.Bounds);
        ControlPaint.DrawFocusRectangle(e.Graphics, e.Bounds, fore, Color.FromArgb(254, 128, 62));
        TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, e.Node.Text, font, e.Bounds, fore, TextFormatFlags.GlyphOverhangPadding);
    }
    else
    {
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(64,64,64)), e.Bounds);
        TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, e.Node.Text, font, e.Bounds, fore, TextFormatFlags.GlyphOverhangPadding);
    }
}
}
```

Unfortunetly, this changes only the background colour of the selection as the FullRowSelect property was off. So I get the item highlighted with my own colour as long as the text of the item is, but the whole rest of the row is still blue and not changed to my own colour.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: It looks like you are just grabbing the Node Bounds and drawing the background to that.  You need to find a way to grab the entire row bounds and draw that instead of just the Node Bounds.  I've been looking all over for a solution to help you out with this, but I've found nothing.  Also, the best option for seeing if it is selected is to check e.Node.IsSelected.  That will make that check more efficient.  Good luck with that, but everything I found said it was not possible.  I'm sure you can find a way if you search enough, though.  Nothing is impossible, just very difficult sometimes.

Comment: "OwnerDrawText" means what it says, you only get to draw the text.  OwnerDrawAll isn't a heckofalot of fun.